# How to extract data from JS array in an html file to VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I'm trying to automate retrieval of information from an online source at my new internship. I've managed to create code that manages to open up the password-protected site, and navigate two additional pages to get to the page I want. However, this page has information tabulated that I am having trouble extracting. The information seems o be stored inside a javascript file being accessed by the HTML. Is there a way to get this info and put it in an excel worksheet?

Here is my code so far...Unfortunately, I can't display the URL, as I am not sure if my company will allow it.

```
            Sub AutomateIE()

            Dim URL As String
            Dim URL2 As String
            Dim IE As Object
            Dim objPage As Object

            Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            IE.Visible = True 

            URL = "URL" 
            URL2 = "URL2" 
            URL3 = "URL3"
            IE.navigate URL
            Do While IE.ReadyState < 4: 
            DoEvents: Loop
            Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4:
            DoEvents: Loop

            Set objPage = IE.document
            objPage.getelementbyid("ucLogin_txtLogonID").Value = "Employee name" 
            objPage.getelementbyid("ucLogin_txtLogonPassword").Value = "Employee password"
            Application.SendKeys "{Return}", True '
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) 
            IE.navigate URL2
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
            IE.navigate URL3 

            End Sub
```

Comment: "The information seems to be stored inside a javascript file being accessed by the HTML" ... well that will need a little bit more description for this to be a good question. It's possible you can log in and then use `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest` to simply download the file. Alternatively, talk to your IT administrators and see if they can point you in the right direction for automating this data retrieval. Do you own the information? Is it in a database? If so this should be easy. If this isn't a webpage you own you should look at using their API, which may cost money, but also may be a simple url

Answer (score 0):

If it a static value defined in the script file , you can use XMLHTTP60 to get the responseText of the script file.

Such as :

`var arr = ["hello", "world"];`

Let's say you want "world"

Then load up the script in a ScriptControl object, and evaluate it:

```
Dim script As IHTMLScriptElement
Set script = doc.getElementById("myScript") 'may need another way to identify

Dim sControl As ScriptControl 'needs reference to Miscrosoft Script Control 1.0
Set sControl = New ScriptControl
sControl.Language = "JScript"

Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
With xhr
     .Open "GET", URL3.Path & "/" & script.src, False 'define full path to script file properly 
     'if necessary change above path to full script src URL
     .send
     Dim jsText As String
     jsText = .responseText
End With
sControl.AddCode jsText 'adds the contents of the script file to ScriptControl object

Dim v As Variant
v = sControl.Eval("arr[1]")

MsgBox v
```